# use of ? (special character) in servername of httpd-vhost.conf

Tags: escaping, xampp

i have created a new virtual host which is as under:

```
<VirtualHost http://developer.com/TimeService/V1/gettime:80>
```

ServerName http://developer.com/TimeService/V1/gettime

DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/developer.com

ServerAdmin admin@developer.com

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride FileInfo

Order allow,deny

Allow from all

i want the first 2 line to look as

```
<VirtualHost http://developer.com/TimeService/V1/gettime?appid:80>
```

ServerName http://developer.com/TimeService/V1/gettime?appid

the problem i am facing is when i put ? (special character) in the above http the apache server refuses to start.

how should i make the apache to recognize this??

Answer (score 0):

Server name is restrict to fully qualified domain name,
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername

You may use rewrite or redirect instead.

Comment: can you please share how to use rewrite or redirect for my query!!

Comment: First of all, change to ServerName developer.com

Comment: Depends on your configuration, you can use <VirtualHost *:80> . You don't need to rewrite if 'gettime' was the script filename of your API. You may follow the guide for rewriting, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html .